# Best practice for maintaining lists of redirect urls with IIS 8?

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, iis-8, windows-server

Some website changes caused redirect lists with 400+ URLs. What is the best way to maintain these? Adding them one by one is not a good option. Adding them to the the web-config causes the file to grow to the point of the system being unable to read it.

Is there a way to maintain a separate file with redirects in IIS 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience best way is to use rewrite maps:

**Create rewriteMaps.config**

```
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
        <add key="/test.aspx" value="/test2.aspx" />
        <add key="/aboutus.aspx" value="/about" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

**Create rewriteRules.config**

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Rule for Redirects">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>  
</rules>
```

In web.config use `configSource` attribute

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps configSource="rewriteMaps.config" />
    <rules configSource="rewriteRules.config" />
</rewrite>
```

Benefits of this structure

- Web.config small and clean
- You can put *complex* redirects/rewrites with conditions in rewriteRules.config
- You can put simple redirects (redirect `pathA` to `pathB`) directly into rewriteMaps.config as key-value pair

Comment: Thank you, Victor! Does webconfig allow multiple rewritemaps entries in case the rewriteMaps.config becomes larger than 256kb? Also, is the execution order the same as the entries in `<rewrite>`?

Comment: Unfortunately - no. You can use only one rewrite map file. Execution order should be the same

Comment: There's also a custom URLRewrite provider, FileMapProvider which uses a plain delimited text file.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work on my system and may be out of date: